# JSON Data from api

Tags: json, getjson

I would like to extract some JSON data from the following url: 
`http://weather.news24.com/sa/johannesburg`.

I used the Google developer tools which gave me some JSON and when I tried some online JSON validators, it's failing somehow on dates.  Is there anyway I can get around the issue and correctly get the selected city JSON data?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any more specific data? json example? where do you want to implement the API?

Comment: for now I just need to get the json and extract things like city's name, temparature (min and max), @FericoSamuel

Comment: Couldn't you use a real REST API like [OpenWeatherMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWeatherMap)? The following GET Request returns weather data like temp, wind, condition: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=johannesburg,za&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98

Comment: I wish I could but I can not, it's client specification. @Mr.Polywhirl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site does not offer a RESful service, then you may need to ask them if you want to scrape their page. Web page scraping is very tedious and the site's DOM structure could change at any time. There is no guarantee.

---

## Page Scraping

You can scrape the page and convert the table data into a JSON object. I copied the DOM of the webpage as a bassis for this implementation.

If you generate the results below, the following response should be at the bottom.

```
{
  "windSpeed": "13km/h",
  "windDirection": "NW",
  "humidity": "35%",
  "dewPoint": "14",
  "comfortLevel": "30°C",
  "chanceOfRain": "10%",
  "sunrise": "5:57AM",
  "sunset": "6:45PM",
  "moonrise": "6:34PM",
  "moonset": "5:30AM",
  "moonPhase": "Full moon"
}
```

#### Example

```js
// jQuery Plugins
(function($) {
    $.reduce = function(arr, fnReduce, valueInitial) {
        if (Array.prototype.reduce) {
            return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arr, fnReduce, valueInitial);
        }
        $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
            valueInitial = fnReduce.call(null, valueInitial, value, index, arr);
        });
        return valueInitial;
    };
})(jQuery);

// Used to convert a sequence of words to camelCase.
function camelCase(input) { 
    return input.toLowerCase().replace(/\s(.)/g, function(match, group1) {
        return group1.toUpperCase();
    });
}

// Main
$(function() {
  // Replace relative links with absolute.
  $('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://weather.news24.com/' + $(this).attr('src'));
  });

  // Find all table rows and grab the key-value pairs.
  var data = $.reduce($('#forecastContent tr'), function(map, tr) {
    var td = $(tr).find('td'), key, value;
    if (td.length === 2) {
      key = $(td.get(0)).text();
      value = $(td.get(1)).text();
    } else if (td.length === 3) {
      key = $(td.get(1)).text();
      value = $(td.get(2)).text();
    }
    if (key != null && key.trim().length > 0) {
     map[camelCase(key)] = value;
    }
    return map;
  }, {});

  $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.currentConditionsHeader {
  color: #1F38B7;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.forecast7DayBlockEmbedded {
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #EAEFF2;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.forecastHeading {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #D6F1FC;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
}
#response {
  background: #EEE;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="forecastContent">
  <table cellpadding="0" celspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="divCurrentOne" class="currentConditionsOneTable" style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <div class="float-l">
              <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" class="currentConditionsOneTable">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="currentConditionsHeader" style="vertical-align:middle;"> <img tyle="vertical-align:middle;" src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/2.gif">LOW 17°C &nbsp;&nbsp; HIGH 24°C </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Provide space and set column widths -->
                  <tr>
                    <td style="width:110px;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="width:110px;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- end spacer and width definition row -->
                  <tr>
                    <td>Wind Speed</td>
                    <td class="bold">13km/h</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Wind Direction</td>
                    <td class="bold">NW</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Humidity</td>
                    <td class="bold">35%</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Dew Point</td>
                    <td class="bold">14</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Comfort Level</td>
                    <td class="bold">30°C</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Chance of Rain</td>
                    <td class="bold">10%</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="divAstronomy" class="currentConditionsAstronomyTable" style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <div class="float-l">
              <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" class="currentConditionsAstronomyTable">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Provide space and set column widths -->
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="width:100%;">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- end spacer and width definition row -->
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Sunrise</td>
                    <td class="bold">5:57AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Sunset</td>
                    <td class="bold">6:45PM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="bold">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" class="currentConditionsMoonImage"><img src="/Images/Icons/Moon/cw_full_moon.gif"></td>
                    <td>Moonrise</td>
                    <td class="bold">6:34PM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Moonset</td>
                    <td class="bold">5:30AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Moon Phase</td>
                    <td class="bold">Full moon</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" id="div7DayForecast" style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;">
          <div class="forecast7DayEmbeddedContainer">
            <div class="forecast7DayContainer">
              <br>
              <br>
              <div id="7dayforecast" class="forecastHeading">7 Day Forecast</div>
              <div class="forecast7DayBlockEmbedded"> Tuesday
                <br> <img src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/2.gif">
                <br> 17°C - 27°C </div>
              <div class="forecast7DayBlockEmbedded"> Wednesday
                <br> <img src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/33.gif">
                <br> 17°C - 28°C </div>
              <div class="forecast7DayBlockEmbedded"> Thursday
                <br> <img src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/33.gif">
                <br> 16°C - 29°C </div>
              <div class="forecast7DayBlockEmbedded"> Friday
                <br> <img src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/33.gif">
                <br> 17°C - 28°C </div>
              <div class="forecast7DayBlockEmbedded"> Saturday
                <br> <img src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/4.gif">
                <br> 16°C - 27°C </div>
              <div class="forecast7DayBlockEmbedded"> Sunday
                <br> <img src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/22.gif">
                <br> 16°C - 26°C </div>
              <div class="forecast7DayBlockEmbedded"> Monday
                <br> <img src="/Images/Icons/Forecasts/4.gif">
                <br> 15°C - 27°C </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<hr />
<h2>Response</h2>
<pre>
  <code id="response"></code>
</pre>
```

---

## RESTful Options

There are free REST APIs that return JSON weather data. All you need to do is sign up and receive a key.

#### OpenWeatherMap

**API:** http://openweathermap.org/api

**Request:** `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=johannesburg,za&appid=YOUR_KEY`

Response

```
{
    coord: {
        lon: 28.04,
        lat: -26.2
    },
    weather: [{
        id: 801,
        main: "Clouds",
        description: "few clouds",
        icon: "02d"
    }],
    base: "cmc stations",
    main: {
        temp: 304.367,
        pressure: 852.81,
        humidity: 26,
        temp_min: 304.367,
        temp_max: 304.367,
        sea_level: 1022.08,
        grnd_level: 852.81
    },
    wind: {
        speed: 2.51,
        deg: 296.507
    },
    clouds: {
        all: 20
    },
    dt: 1456147770,
    sys: {
        message: 0.0116,
        country: "ZA",
        sunrise: 1456113434,
        sunset: 1456159501
    },
    id: 993800,
    name: "Johannesburg",
    cod: 200
}
```

#### Weather Underground

**API:** https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/

**Request:** `http://api.wunderground.com/api/YOUR_KEY/conditions/q/ZA/Johannesburg.json`

Response

```
{
    response: {
        version: "0.1",
        termsofService: "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
        features: {
            conditions: 1
        }
    },
    current_observation: {
        image: {
            url: "http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
            title: "Weather Underground",
            link: "http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        display_location: {
            full: "Johannesburg, South Africa",
            city: "Johannesburg",
            state: "",
            state_name: "South Africa",
            country: "ZA",
            country_iso3166: "ZA",
            zip: "00000",
            magic: "1",
            wmo: "68368",
            latitude: "-26.12999916",
            longitude: "28.22999954",
            elevation: "1700.00000000"
        },
        observation_location: {
            full: "Johannesburg, ",
            city: "Johannesburg",
            state: "",
            country: "ZA",
            country_iso3166: "ZA",
            latitude: "-26.13077927",
            longitude: "28.24378967",
            elevation: "5643 ft"
        },
        estimated: {},
        station_id: "FAOR",
        observation_time: "Last Updated on February 22, 3:30 PM SAST",
        observation_time_rfc822: "Mon, 22 Feb 2016 15:30:00 +0200",
        observation_epoch: "1456147800",
        local_time_rfc822: "Mon, 22 Feb 2016 15:44:41 +0200",
        local_epoch: "1456148681",
        local_tz_short: "SAST",
        local_tz_long: "Africa/Johannesburg",
        local_tz_offset: "+0200",
        weather: "Scattered Clouds",
        temperature_string: "84 F (29 C)",
        temp_f: 84,
        temp_c: 29,
        relative_humidity: "29%",
        wind_string: "From the WNW at 10 MPH",
        wind_dir: "WNW",
        wind_degrees: 290,
        wind_mph: 10,
        wind_gust_mph: 0,
        wind_kph: 17,
        wind_gust_kph: 0,
        pressure_mb: "1020",
        pressure_in: "30.12",
        pressure_trend: "0",
        dewpoint_string: "48 F (9 C)",
        dewpoint_f: 48,
        dewpoint_c: 9,
        heat_index_string: "NA",
        heat_index_f: "NA",
        heat_index_c: "NA",
        windchill_string: "NA",
        windchill_f: "NA",
        windchill_c: "NA",
        feelslike_string: "84 F (29 C)",
        feelslike_f: "84",
        feelslike_c: "29",
        visibility_mi: "6.2",
        visibility_km: "10.0",
        solarradiation: "--",
        UV: "6",
        precip_1hr_string: "-9999.00 in (-9999.00 mm)",
        precip_1hr_in: "-9999.00",
        precip_1hr_metric: "--",
        precip_today_string: "0.00 in (0.0 mm)",
        precip_today_in: "0.00",
        precip_today_metric: "0.0",
        icon: "partlycloudy",
        icon_url: "http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        forecast_url: "http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/68368.html",
        history_url: "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/FAOR/2016/2/22/DailyHistory.html",
        ob_url: "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=-26.13077927,28.24378967",
        nowcast: ""
    }
}
```

Comment: @SlangI'mmatalk: I updated my answer to include a web-scraping technique using jQuery.

Comment: Will soon go through it have to read about and the DOM you mententioned

Comment: @SlangI'mmatalk: DOM is an acronym for Document Object Model. It is the tree-structure of nodes (tags) in the HTML document. Data should not rely on the structure of the document; it should be the reverse. Pulling data out of a page requires a lot of effort., whereas placing data in a document is easy.